# executing native meta transaction through upgradeable proxy does not work

Tags: solidity, meta-transactions

I have 3 contracts, `UChildERC20`, `UChildERC20Proxy` and `USDTGASLESSTRANSFERPROXY`, deal is that i generate `sigR`, `sigS` and `sigV` on frontend, and function signature in `USDTGASLESSTRANSFERPROXY` and call `executeMetaTransaction` function with those arguments through `USDTGASLESSTRANSFERPROXY`. if I use `UChildERC20` address when calling the USDTGASLESSTRANSFERPROXY's method that calls `executeMetaTransaction` method, it works fine, but if i use UChildERC20Proxy address it returns "Signer and signature do not match" error.

I am copying Polygon's USDT contracts code and deploying it on Mumbai Testnet to test. here's the addresses of the contracts that i copy.

Proxy: "https://polygonscan.com/token/0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f#code"

Implementation: "https://polygonscan.com/address/0x7ffb3d637014488b63fb9858e279385685afc1e2#code"

And my `USDTGASLESSTRANSFERPROXY`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@opengsn/contracts/src/ERC2771Recipient.sol";

abstract contract USDT is IERC20 {
    uint256 public decimals;

    function executeMetaTransaction(
        address userAddress,
        bytes memory functionSignature,
        bytes32 sigR,
        bytes32 sigS,
        uint8 sigV
    ) public payable virtual returns (bytes memory);
}

contract UsdtGaslessTransferProxy is ERC2771Recipient, Ownable, AccessControl {
    using SafeERC20 for USDT;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    address public mainContractAddress;
    USDT public usdt;

    constructor(
        address _usdtAddress,
        address _mainContractAddress,
        address _forwarder
    ) {
        usdt = USDT(_usdtAddress);
        mainContractAddress = _mainContractAddress;
        _setTrustedForwarder(_forwarder);
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function _msgSender()
        internal
        view
        override(Context, ERC2771Recipient)
        returns (address sender)
    {
        sender = ERC2771Recipient._msgSender();
    }

    function _msgData()
        internal
        view
        override(Context, ERC2771Recipient)
        returns (bytes calldata)
    {
        return ERC2771Recipient._msgData();
    }

    function setTrustedForwarder(address pForwarder)
        public
        onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE)
    {
        _setTrustedForwarder(pForwarder);
    }

    function delegateApprovalMetaTransaction(
        uint256 amount,
        bytes32 sigR,
        bytes32 sigS,
        uint8 sigV
    ) public returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory functionSignature = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "approve(address,uint256)",
            mainContractAddress,
            amount
        );
        bytes memory returnData = usdt.executeMetaTransaction(
            _msgSender(),
            functionSignature,
            sigR,
            sigS,
            sigV
        );
        return returnData;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The `getDomainseparator` function used for verifying signatures returns different values based on the chainid they are deployed.